# Out-of-context SetWinEventHook() not getting any events

Tags: c++, windows

Why is this program not getting any events ?

This is a global (out-of-context) hook (with its message loop) that's configured for `[EVENT_MIN , EVENT_MAX]`, it should drown in events.

Tried both Console & Window types :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

HWINEVENTHOOK g_hook;
bool stop = false;

// Callback function that handles events.
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
  LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
  DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
  cout<<"Got event "<<event<<'\n'<<std::flush;
}

int EventHook() {

  cout <<"thread EventHook running\n"<<std::flush;
  g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_MIN , EVENT_MAX,  // Range of events.
    NULL,                   // Handle to DLL.
    HandleWinEvent,         // The callback.
    0, 0,                   // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
  cout <<"Hooked\n"<<std::flush;

  MSG msg;
  while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    if(stop) return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}

// Both console & window are eventless
//int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
//  int argc;
//  auto *argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  std::thread t1(EventHook); cout<<"start thread EventHook\n"<<std::flush;
  //Sleep(std::wcstoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);
  Sleep(std::strtoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);

  stop = true;
  t1.join();

  UnhookWinEvent(g_hook);
  return 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PeekMessage()` is a non-blocking function. It always exits immediately, returning `TRUE` if a message was retrieved, otherwise returning `FALSE`.  So, as soon as your thread's message queue is empty (as it likely is initially), `PeekMessage()` will return `FALSE` causing your loop to end, and thus your program to exit.

In other words, your program is not likely to run long enough to receive any events.

You need to use `GetMessage()` instead. It will allow your loop to block your thread waiting for new messages to arrive.

However, that means your `stop` variable *by itself* is insufficient to end your thread, as you might not receive new messages for awhile (if at all) after you have changed the variable's value. The loop may be blocked on `GetMessage()` and not see the variable's new value right away (if at all).

You can work around that by using `PostThreadMessage()` to post a benign message (like `WM_NULL`) to the thread's message queue to "wake up" `GetMessage()` if it is blocked. Or, just get rid of the `stop` variable altogether and post a `WM_QUIT` message to your thread's message queue, which will cause `GetMessage()` to return `0`.

Also, you need to call `UnhookWinEvent()` in the same thread that calls   `SetWinEventHook()`.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

HWINEVENTHOOK g_hook;
bool stop = false;
DWORD g_tid = 0;

// Callback function that handles events.
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
  LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
  DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
  cout<<"Got event "<<event<<'\n'<<std::flush;
}

int EventHook() {

  g_tid = GetCurrentThreadId();
  WakeByAddressSingle(&g_tid);

  cout <<"thread EventHook running\n"<<std::flush;
  g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_MIN , EVENT_MAX,  // Range of events.
    NULL,                   // Handle to DLL.
    HandleWinEvent,         // The callback.
    0, 0,                   // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
  if (!g_hook) {
    cout <<"Error in Hook\n"<<std::flush;
    return;
  }
  cout <<"Hooked\n"<<std::flush;

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    if (stop) break;
  }

  UnhookWinEvent(g_hook);
  return 0;
}

// Both console & window are eventless
//int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
//  int argc;
//  auto *argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  std::thread t1(EventHook);
  cout<<"start thread EventHook\n"<<std::flush;

  DWORD tid = 0;
  WaitOnAddress(&g_tid, &tid, sizeof(DWORD), INFINITE);

  //Sleep(std::wcstoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);
  Sleep(std::strtoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);

  PostThreadMessage(g_tid, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
  t1.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

HWINEVENTHOOK g_hook;
DWORD g_tid = 0;

// Callback function that handles events.
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
  LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
  DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
  cout<<"Got event "<<event<<'\n'<<std::flush;
}

int EventHook() {

  g_tid = GetCurrentThreadId();
  WakeByAddressSingle(&g_tid);

  cout <<"thread EventHook running\n"<<std::flush;
  g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_MIN , EVENT_MAX,  // Range of events.
    NULL,                   // Handle to DLL.
    HandleWinEvent,         // The callback.
    0, 0,                   // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
  if (!g_hook) {
    cout <<"Error in Hook\n"<<std::flush;
    return;
  }
  cout <<"Hooked\n"<<std::flush;

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  UnhookWinEvent(g_hook);
  return 0;
}

// Both console & window are eventless
//int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
//  int argc;
//  auto *argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  std::thread t1(EventHook);
  cout<<"start thread EventHook\n"<<std::flush;

  DWORD tid = 0;
  WaitOnAddress(&g_tid, &tid, sizeof(DWORD), INFINITE);

  //Sleep(std::wcstoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);
  Sleep(std::strtoul(argv[1],nullptr,10) * 1000);

  PostThreadMessage(g_tid, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
  t1.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Never even read the message loop code (a hasty copy-paste by a colleague). You can use `GetThreadId(t1.native_handle())` to  `PostThreadMessage()`, and since posted messages can't be dispatched anyway (not associated to a window), I reduced the loop to a single `GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);` (just to create a msg queue, WM_QUIT still needed to guarantee it returns ! console-apps-no-msg). The hook seems to be doing its own get() (only needs a msg queue to *exist*). I then use an simple event to stop t1 (no WaitOnAddress on Win7, good thinking !).

Comment: It is not enough that the queue *exists*, the thread needs to actively retrieve messages for the queue to be processed. But `GetMessage()` will automatically dispatch non-queued messages for you. In any case, there is no point in waiting on an Event object to signal termination if you are also posting `WM_QUIT` to signal termination. That is just redundant. If you really want to use an Event object, then I would suggest making the thread use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` in a loop, calling `PeekMessage()` whenever messages are pending, and ending the loop when the Event is signaled.

Comment: You're right about the event, since `main()` is Posting a message (any one, could be `WM_NULL`), `GetMessage()` is sure to return. A single `GetMessage()` is enough (no loop needed), since it will dispatch all sent (system) messages.

Comment: The event would add control to make sure our `main()` decides when to stop the hook, in case `t1` receives a foreign posted msg, but who would post such a msg ? Maybe in a more elaborate scenario..